# Prototype object properties have wierd behaviour

Tags: javascript, prototype

Say I have the following:

```
var Car = function() {
}
Car.prototype.config = {
    color: 'red'
}
Car.prototype.color = 'red';

var car1 = new Car();
var car2 = new Car();
car1.config.color = 'green';
car1.color = 'green';
console.log(car2.config.color) //green but expected red
console.log(car2.color) //red as expected
```

Anyone knows why prototype object properties act as 'static' properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding `car2.config.color` :

That's expected because all the instance of `Car` share the same prototype, and thus the same properties of that prototype. So when you change one, you change the other ones.

In fact that's the point : it lets you for example have one unique function (prototype is most often used for functions) for all instances, which is cheaper.

If you want to have distinct `config`, don't attach it to the prototype but to the instance.

Regarding `car2.color` :

You expected it, so maybe I don't need to explain it, but here's what happens :

- when you don't set `car.color`, reading that property looks for the prototype chain until a property with that name is found, so it returns `'red'`.
- when you set `car.color`, reading it, by the same process, returns this property you've set

Comment: Great and simple explanation.